# System boots with MBR, but not with GPT

Tags: partition, boot-loader, gpt, mbr, yocto

I have a Linux image made with Yocto that boots on a Pocketbeagle. For the learning experience, I'm trying to move it to using GPT.

For MBR, I am using the following beaglebone-yocto.wks description:

```
part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 4 --size 16 --sourceparams="loader=u-boot" --use-uuid
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=ext4 --label root --align 4 --use-uuid

bootloader --append="console=ttyS0,115200"
```

Now for GPT, I thought I could just change the `bootloader` line by adding `--ptable gpt`, but after I do that, my image just does not boot anymore on the Pocketbeagle. So I also tried to modify the `--align` option of the `part` command and to add `rootfstype=ext4` to the `bootloader` command, but I have no idea why (I saw it on a different, unrelated example online). The commands look like this:

```
part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=vfat --label boot --part-name boot --active --align 1024 --sourceparams="loader=u-boot" --use-uuid
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=ext4 --label root --part-name system --align 1024 --use-uuid

bootloader --ptable gpt --append="rootfstype=ext4 console=ttyS0,115200"
```

I am a bit stuck at this point, as I do not know if my Pocketbeagle does not boot because it does not support GPT at all (could it be? How can I know?) or if I did it wrong with the commands above.

Would love to get some insights and get to understand GPT better :-)

Comment: Do not know Pocketbeagle, but grub does not correct install for BIOS boot on gpt partitioned drives unless you also have a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. I have used gpt with BIOS starting in 2010, but had to have bios_grub for it to work. Then with UEFI, it needs an ESP - efi system partition. With MBR, grub normally has core.img in the sectors just after MBR. With gpt those sectors do not exist, so you have to have the bios_grub. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html

Comment: Right. But does GPT require grub? With MBR I do not think I am using grub at the moment, it just boots to u-boot...

Comment: No, other boot loaders should work. But they may have their own requirements. Google tells me uboot knows about gpt. https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/uboot/doc/README.gpt So it should work.https://forum.doozan.com/read.php?3,4931

Comment: Yes, I was more worried about something like "the pocketbeagle cannot load GPT because it expects something smaller, and hence only MBR can work there"